# RxJava using Kotlin - how to synchronize 2 asynchronous methods, refactor from Java

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have 2 collections, which buffer location update events:

```
     private List<LocationGeoEvent> mUpdateGeoEvents = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<LocationRSSIEvent> mUpdateRSSIEvents = new ArrayList<>();
```

There is also present in my code:

```
        private final ScheduledExecutorService mSaveDataExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    private boolean mSaveDataScheduled;
    private final Object mEventsMonitor = new Object();

    private ScheduledFuture<?> mScheduledStopLocationUpdatesFuture;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService mStopLocationUpdatesExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

I add event to this colections like this:

```
    public void appendGeoEvent(LocationGeoEvent event) {
            synchronized (mEventsMonitor) {
                mUpdateGeoEvents.add(event);
                scheduleSaveEvents();
            }
    }
```

The same goes for the RSSI event

Now, the scheduleSaveEvents method looks like this:

```
      private void scheduleSaveEvents() {

        synchronized (mSaveDataExecutor) {
            if (!mSaveDataScheduled) {
                mSaveDataScheduled = true;
                mSaveDataExecutor.schedule(
                        new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                synchronized (mSaveDataExecutor) {
                                    saveEvents(false);
                                    mSaveDataScheduled = false;
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        30,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        }

    }
```

The problem is, that i need to synchronize the other method which stops the updates. It is triggered like this:

```
      private void scheduleStopLocationUpdates() {

        synchronized (mStopLocationUpdatesExecutor) {
            if (mScheduledStopLocationUpdatesFuture != null)
                mScheduledStopLocationUpdatesFuture.cancel(true);

            mScheduledStopLocationUpdatesFuture = mStopLocationUpdatesExecutor.schedule(
                    new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            synchronized (mStopLocationUpdatesExecutor) {
                                stopLocationUpdates();
                                saveEvents(true);
                                cleanAllReadingsData();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    45,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

    }
```

In the saveEvents method i do:

```
    private void saveEvents(boolean locationUpdatesAboutToStop) {

        synchronized (mEventsMonitor) {
            if (mUpdateGeoEvents.size() > 0 || mUpdateRSSIEvents.size() > 0) {

                 //do something with the data from buffered collection arrayLists and with the boolean locationUpdatesAboutToStop

                mUpdateGeoEvents.clear();
                mUpdateRSSIEvents.clear();
            }

        }

    }
```

Is there a way to refactor this simplier to RxJava using Kotlin?

**UPDATE**

Here is my appendRSSIevents method:

```
    private fun appendRSSIEvent(event: LocationRSSIEvent) {
    synchronized(mEventsMonitor) {
        if (!shouldSkipRSSIData(event.nexoIdentifier)) {
            mUpdateRSSIEvents.add(event)
            acknowledgeDevice(event.nexoIdentifier)
            scheduleSaveEvents()
            startLocationUpdates()
        } else
            removeExpiredData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can buffer the two streams of data and then combine them for saving. Also, you can use the buffer trigger to stop the updates as well.

```
PublishSubject<LocationGeoEvent> mUpdateGeoEventsSubject = PublishSubject.create();
PublishSubject<LocationRSSIEvent> mUpdateRSSIEventsSubject = PublishSubject.create();

public void appendGeoEvent(LocationGeoEvent event) {
  mUpdateGeoEventsSubject.onNext( event );
  triggerSave.onNext( Boolean.TRUE );
}
```

and the same for RSS feed.

Now we need triggers that will be used to drive the saving step.

```
PublishSubject<Boolean> triggerSave = PublishSubject.create();
PublishSubject<Boolean> triggerStopAndSave = PublishSubject.create();

Observable<Boolean> normalSaveTrigger = triggerSave.debounce( 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
Observable<Boolean> trigger = Observable.merge( normalSaveTrigger, triggerStopAndSave );
```

The `trigger` observable fires when either the normal save process fires or if we are stopping the save.

```
private void saveEvents(
  List<LocationGeoEvent> geo,
  List<LocationRSSIEvent> rss,
  boolean locationUpdatesAboutToStop) {

    synchronized (mEventsMonitor) {
        if (geo.size() > 0 || rss.size() > 0) {
             //do something with the data from buffered collection arrayLists and with the boolean locationUpdatesAboutToStop
        }
    }
}
private void scheduleStopLocationUpdates() {
  stopLocationUpdates();
  triggerStopAndSave.onNext( Boolean.FALSE );
  cleanAllReadingsData();
}

Observable.zip( mUpdateGeoEventsSubject.buffer( trigger ),
                mUpdateRSSIEventsSubject.buffer( trigger ),
                trigger, (geo, rss, trgr) -> saveEvents(geo, rss, trgr) )
  .subscribe();
```

You will still need to some tuning with respect to multi-threading and safety. The first step would be to turn the various subjects into `SerializedSubject`s so that multiple threads can emit events.

If you want `saveEvents` to run on a particular scheduler, you will either need to add an intermediate data structure, a triple, to pass the parameters through `observeOn()` operator, or apply `observeOn()` operator to each of `zip()` arguments.

Comment: Thanks, i will try to work with your solution, but have you tried this solution in Android Studio IDE? Something is wrong with the Observable.zip(..) part. However i am using Kotlin(this is wrong in Kotlin too). IDE says 'Cannot infer functional interface type' and underlines the (geo, rss, trgr) -> saveEvents(geo, rss, trgr) part

Comment: Oh, sorry. `saveEvents` should return a boolean so that there is a value to pass on.

Comment: Also i didn't mention important thing about appendRssiEvent - it looks somehow different, maybe it don't change much to your implementation. I updated my question. Also, the scheduleStopLocationUpdates is scheduled in different time than the scheduleStopLocation, to 45 seconds. So i guess it is more complications. Thank you for your help, i really appreciate it.

Comment: Also, if you can please check if this Observable.zip(..) can be converted to Kotlin, i can't convert it. The IDE underlines the .zip and says this: https://gist.github.com/oksett/a406c8d6e2cae3d96fa3c19535e4b138

Comment: I have no experience with Kotlin. I suspect that it does something fancy with type inference that is getting in the way.

Comment: Also, i want to be able to not have empty buffer when the stopAndSave trigger will occur. I want to have boolean locationUpdatesAboutToStop set to false when normalSave occurs, and set to true when triggerStopAndSave will occur. When the triggerStopAndSave will occur i want to still have items in my buffer to do something with them

Comment: The interval is also not working. I want to be able to invoke save after 30 seconds from the first event occur, and not schedule anymore. It appears it schedules only from the last event

Comment: I need such mechanism, because i need to store those events in Database, so i must not insert everything at once

Comment: You should have enough information to build your application code. You can use `sample()` operator to delay triggering the save, instead of `debounce()`. You can put the code into a test harness and check out all the different scenarios, and adjust the timings, and change the timing operators.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I get into something strange, i tried to log each of those normalSaveTrigger(that, which is scheduled to 30 seconds) action in doOnNext and it always logs 3 each times(no 1 as i thought) Maybe you know what can cause this?

Comment: It sounds like the observable has multiple subscriptions, which makes sense. Change the definition of `normalSaveTrigger` to add `.share()` at the end and see if that works.